# Turtlebot Create2 base_link location

Tags: ros, base-link, create2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to REP 105, `base_link` should be in the center of rotation of the base, in this case a iRobot Create 2. What I can't figure out is where it is vertically. Is `base_link` at floor level or at the bottom of the robot or at the top or some other place?
Thanks,
luketheduke

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257142/turtlebot-create2-base_link-location/) by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2017-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A good place for the center of rotation would be the center of the wheels axle. In the case of the Create platform this should be about where the main power button is horizontally and center of the wheel vertically. The bottom (or floor) of the robot should be where you'd find a `base_footprint` frame.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2017-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2